# Count values of a column

Tags: mysql, count

I've got two database tables:

```
Persons
id   user   product
1     1       3
2     1       5
3     1       7

products
id   kilo
3     8
5     15
7     3
```

I'm wondering how to count values from a database, in this case I want to get the total kilo's of products for user 1. The result should be '26'. Is this possible?

```
SELECT kilo FROM `products` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `product` FROM `person` WHERE `user` = '1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put kilo inside the sum() function, like so:

```
SELECT sum(kilo) 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT `product` 
    FROM `person` 
    WHERE `user` = '1'
);
```

Comment: When I tried this I get as result: Resource id #5

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mysql or php, but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754320/figuring-out-why-i-am-getting-a-resource-id-5-error

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem, use `SUM` and join in 1 query.

```
SELECT SUM(`kilo`) total_kilo
FROM `person` 
    INNER JOIN `products` 
    on `person`.`product` = `products`.`id`;
```

Or selecting/counting for user 1 alone

```
SELECT SUM(`kilo`) total_kilo 
FROM `person` 
    INNER JOIN `products` 
    on `person`.`product` = `products`.`id` 
WHERE `person`.`user` =1;
```

Or selecting/counting for *every* user

```
SELECT `person`.`user`, SUM(`kilo`) total_kilo 
FROM `person` 
    INNER JOIN `products` 
    on `person`.`product` = `products`.`id` 
GROUP BY `person`.`user`;
```